# how can we write large DataFrame into excel file quickly in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dask

```
import pandas as pd  
df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/10lakhhhhh.csv") 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/df/media/pandasEx.xlsx',engine ='xlsxwriter') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='10lakhhhhh')  
writer.save()
```

Comment: You could try if `openpyxl`is faster than the pandas Excelwriter. In my tests it has been faster so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new module called `modin`. It can be used as below to read huge data quickly:

**Install**:

```
pip install modin
```

**Code**:

```
import modin.pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/10lakhhhhh.csv')
```

Comment: but this will read csv ..i want to write csv dataframe in excel quikely

Comment: If I am not wrong, if you try `pd.to_excel(..)` with this...it will do that also fast..since you have now defined `modin.pandas` as `pd`

Comment: but modin is not installing with python 3.7

Comment: I user python 3.5 and it works..so not sure about it!!

Comment: Couldn't install or it is also taking more time ?